# Dropdown nav on another bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I want to add dropdown to my current nav bar. I tried this code but dropdown content disappeared and now I don´t have any ideas to edit code to this be working. I tried some edits but isn´t do with dropdown. Dropdown, dropbtn was added to previous code. Can you help me with this? Thanks very much!

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="menu.png" />
<title>MENU | Úvodné menu</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
body {
  height: 100%;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange, red);
}
</style>
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: full;
  background-size: ;
}
</style>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}



.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

tyle>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<div class="header">
 <a id="txt" hidden></a>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/6Nkbdb3/dlhemenu-1-1-1.png" class="logo" title="Odhlásiť sa" alt="MENU logo" width="150" height="50" onclick="window.location='/logout.php'"> 
 &nbsp
 <a class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp</i>Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>   


    <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="/welcome.php">Úvodné menu</a>
        <a href="/online.html">Online hodiny</a>
    <a href="/vyplnit.html">Testy na vyplnenie</a>
    <a href="/znamky3.html">Známky</a>
    <a href="/rozvrh.html">Rozvrh hodín</a>
     <a href="/dochadzka.html">Dochádzka</a>
      <a href="/ucenie.html">Učebný materiál</a>
       <a href="/hry.html">Hry</a>
  <a href="/omne.php">O mne</a>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo here:  `tyle></head>`... it has to be `</style></head>`

Comment: can you tell me where? thanks

Comment: I already did... just do a search of `</head>` tag in your code and you will see that typo error in the previous line, where it shows only `tyle>` instead `</style>`

Comment: Thanks but dropdown still isn´t working.

Answer (score 2):

add hover css to display the drop-down content

```
.dropbtn:hover ~ .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I tried to click to dropdown link dropdown menu hide. Can you fix it somehow please? I´m begginner in css. Thanks very mech!

Comment: to `.dropdown-content` class add `top:65px;` and add to css `.dropdown-content:hover{display:block}`